# WCF hosted in IIS, custom autofac service host factory

Tags: .net, wcf, autofac

I am creating a new WCF service which is hosted in IIS. Also using autofac as IOC container. For registering the dependencies I am using autofac modules. Can anyone please tell how can I register modules along with my operation behaviour to custom autofac service factory? Can anyone please provide a sample?